# Magento2: Multistore / Multiwebsite setup on nginx

Tags: magento2, nginx, server-setup

I am trying to setup a multistore or multiwebsite in magento 2. My server is using nginx. Can any one please tell me the steps to work on it.

**What i have tried so far.**

1) By following [magento2 doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html) i made changes in `nginx.magento.conf` and `main.conf` which is located at **/etc/nginx/conf.d/**

2) Made host entry in `/etc/hosts`

3) Made host entry on my windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

But i am not able to get my second website in running state.

Here are the files .

**1) main.conf**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.key;
    server_name magento2-dev.local magento2-demo.local;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2-dev.local;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf.magento2;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    magento2-dev.local base;
    magento2-demo.local site2;
}
```

**Another tried Way**

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.key;
    server_name magento2-dev.local;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2-dev.local;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf.magento2;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.key;
    server_name magento2-demo.local;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2-dev.local;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf.magento2;
}


map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    magento2-dev.local base;
    magento2-demo.local site2;
}
```

**2) nginx.magento.conf**

```
# Magento Vars
# set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/magento/root;
# set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
#
# Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }


root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset off;

add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location /update {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\                                                                                                                                                             .xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
        expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$                                                                                                                                                              {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$                                                                                                                                                              {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ cron\.php {
    deny all;
}

location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=                                                                                                                                                             off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**3) server hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 magento2-demo.local magento2-dev.local
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**4) My Windows hosts file**

```
192.168.56.104 magento2-dev.local
192.168.56.104 magento2-demo.local
```

**My present result is** 
for http://magento2-dev.local/

[image]

and for http://magento2-demo.local/

[image]

Can any one please help me to find my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're listening on magento2-demo.local.

The line `server_name magento2-dev.local;` should contain all appropriate aliases, so in this case `server_name magento2-dev.local magento2-demo.local;` inside your main.conf server entry.

Comment: I am working on LEMP localhost, here is my main url : "http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/" & multi website url : "http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery" How can i use my url into Nginx setup? Shall i use magento2-dev.local instead of http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/ and magento2-demo.local instead of http:// 192.168.1.65:8087/grocery @Jonathan Wommack Thank you